# golang 'go install latest' not working correct

Tags: go

i uploaded my go project to github yesterday today i updated it and add i tag with v1.0.1 version when i use go install @latest it brings the old version v1.0.0 i don't know why i tried to delete all files on repo github and uploaded tha last update version 1.0.1 and try to hit go install @latest but didn't work and also it downloaded v1.0.0 i tries to go clean -modcach but no thing happend the same problem
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution by using:

```
export GOPRIVATE={with my github account}
```